# How to filter for a whole dictionary by a specific value inside it via JSONPath?

Tags: jsonpath

All I (just) leardned about JSONPath is that I can filter/select for parts of a JSON string by giving key names or array indices etc.
The result is *that* key/value I gave in the JSONPath expression.
However, I want to get, as a result, the whole dictionary where inside of it is a key/value pair I want to filter for – not only that key/value pair.

For example, imagine the following JSON string:

```
[
 {
  „date“: „2021-06-18T10:23:45.000+0000“,
  „material“: {
    „key1“: „value1“,
    „key2“: „value2“
  },
  „preset“: {
    „duration“: [ 120, 180 ],
    „increments“: 3,
    „id“: „16“,
    „uniqueId“: „1357924680“
  },
  „userId“: 23456
 },
 {
  „date“: „2021-06-18T08:15:45.000+0000“,
  „material“: {
    „key1“: „value1“,
    „key2“: „value2“
  },
  „preset“: {
    „duration“: [ 180 ],
    „increments“: 1,
    „id“: „10“,
    „uniqueId“: „1797924680“
  },
  „userId“: 23456
 },
 {
  „date“: „2021-06-16T17:12:23.000+0000“,
  „material“: {
    „key1“: „value1“,
    „key2“: „value2“
  },
  „preset“: {
    „duration“: [ 240 ],
    „increments“: 1,
    „id“: „10“,
    „uniqueId“: „1357944680“
  },
  „userId“: 23456
 },
 {
  „date“: „2021-06-09T08:45:45.000+0000“,
  „material“: {
    „key1“: „value1“,
    „key2“: „value2“
  },
  „preset“: {
    „duration“: [ 120, 180 ],
    „increments“: 3,
    „id“: „16“,
    „uniqueId“: „2357924680“
  },
  „userId“: 23456
 }
]
```

Now suppose I want to get those array elements (completely, with all their data) where inside the „preset“ named dictionary the value of „id“ is equal to „16“. What‘s the JSONPath query string for this?
Remember: I don‘t want to get *just* { „id“: „16“, „id“: „16“ } as a result but instead the whole dictionary with both results in this case:

```
 {
  „date“: „2021-06-18T10:23:45.000+0000“,
  „material“: {
    „key1“: „value1“,
    „key2“: „value2“
  },
  „preset“: {
    „duration“: [ 120, 180 ],
    „increments“: 3,
    „id“: „16“,
    „uniqueId“: „1357924680“
  },
  „userId“: 23456
 },
 {
  „date“: „2021-06-09T08:45:45.000+0000“,
  „material“: {
    „key1“: „value1“,
    „key2“: „value2“
  },
  „preset“: {
    „duration“: [ 120, 180 ],
    „increments“: 3,
    „id“: „16“,
    „uniqueId“: „2357924680“
  },
  „userId“: 23456
 }
```

And I don‘t want to do this inside some coding project/a program/source code in any programming language. Instead I have a REST API tool where I can filter JSON responses with a JSONPath query string (it‘s the app „HTTPBot“ for i[Pad]OS).

Here are a few JSONPath examples I tried but don‘t give the result I want:

- `$..preset` – returns *all* the preset dicts (no filtering for those with a certain id value)
- `$..preset.id` – returns all values of all id keys in all preset dicts (again, no filtering for a certain id)
- `$..preset[?(@.id==„16“)]` – this is what I thought should do the trick but in HTTPBot this just returns the same as `$..preset` (maybe I should ask the author of HTTPBot if he implemented JSONPath completely?! )

Comment: Can you show an example of a JSON Path you've tried?

Comment: Certainly, @gregsdennis, I added a few to the post. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$..preset` is going to perform a recursive search for any property (at any depth) called `preset` and return the collection of all the values in those properties.

To get the items, you need to have a selector that acts on them.  Since you want to filter the items, you're looking at the filter selector `[?(<expr>)]`.

Within JSON Path expressions, you can use the `@` to look at each item as the selector iterates the array, and it supports building a path from it.  We want the `@.preset.id` to be `16`, so we can use

```
$[?(@.preset.id=='16')]
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much, Greg, learned a lot here! 

Comment: No worries. Be aware that some implementations employ a 'loose equality' that will auto-convert types, so `'16'==16` would return true. This is NOT what we're building into the [upcoming spec](https://github.com/ietf-wg-jsonpath/draft-ietf-jsonpath-base).

Comment: One little question remains, though. The filtering by id==16 works BUT the result set contains the „date“, „material“, „userId“ data, too. Is there a way to get ONLY the „preset“ dictionary that contains the id key with value 16?

Comment: Oh! Got it! Simply adding a .preset to the expression does the trick, of course! 

Comment: Still got a question here. Imagine I want to filter like above (for an id inside a preset) but then output the date (which is outside of preset) and the uniqueId from inside preset *at the same time*, i.e., with just one JSONPath query string. Is this possible?

Comment: It's probably better to ask a new follow-up question for that.

Comment: Thanks, @gregsdennis, I already figured it out, found about the comma , syntax. However, this only works in my go-to-tool “Paw” on the Mac but not in my go-to-app “HTTPBot” on the iPad … ‍♂️

Comment: Yeah there's quite a bit of variance between implementations, which is why were writing the spec.